# Sockets failing to connect in android

Tags: android, sockets, port

So I have this code that I have been using successfully everywhere, until I tried it in android project. This is the code, its the most simple code.

```
try {
   Socket socket = new Socket();
   socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, port), timeout);
   socket.close();
   openPorts.add(port);
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

this code seems to fail on every single port and think that they are closed, even though the same code works excellent on desktop. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have INTERNET permission in the manifest?

Comment: Hey, that is an excellent point. Never thought of it. Ill give it a try right away

Comment: go to this link :[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611593/send-text-from-android-to-pc-via-wi-fi-connection/40820861#40820861)

Answer (score 1):

You should modify your `AndroidManifest.xml` file and request a permission called `INTERNET`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html