# send text from android to pc via wi-fi connection

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android programming and stackoverflow. I want to create an app that sends some info (like a text) to a PC on the same network (Wi-fi) and read on the PC using a Java app. Any ideas how to get started? Sorry for my bad English

Comment: you are attempting to build a server-client application.

Comment: look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345155/android-receive-and-send-data-through-wifi-connection-to-hardware . It may help you.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Comment: Ask Your Question in this Link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388250/how-to-send-string-from-android-to-pc-over-wifi
I Hope yoursuccessful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use wi-fi manager in client and server programs and set wifi direct between PC and Android.

For the permissions use this:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In server use :

```java
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

And in client :

```
socket = new Socket()
socket.connect("192.168.49.(Server Device wi-fi IP(zero to 255))" , 9000);
```

Then use these methods in both programs for send-receive data

```
DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

//in server
String txt = "Hello from Server to Client\n";           
outputStream.write(txt.getBytes());

//in client 
String message = inputStream.readLine();

socket.close();
```

Server sends the text and client checks the input stream for a '\n' in it.

Answer (score 0):

As user5001333 said, you must build a server-client pattern using sockets, for example.

In Android you can't perform network operations on the main thread so you have to create a background thread (like asynctask) which establish the connection between you (client) and the pc (server).